# JSF and synchronized lazyloading from EntityManager

Tags: jpa, jsf, entitymanager

I know EntityManager is not thread-safe but how to work with this in JSF?

Environment: Tomcat with Java-SE. Not Spring or something like that. Manual transaction management.

If I have an object like (pseudo code):

```
@Entity
class Person {
  @OneToMany(lazy=true)
  List<Address> addresses;

  @ManyToOne(lazy=true)
  Company company;
}
```

Then I have a NamedBean like

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
class PersonBean {
  EntityManager entityManager;

  public PersonBean(EntityManager em) { this.entityManager = em; }

  public Person getPerson() {
    em.find(Person.class, 1);  // load the Person with id=1
  }
}
```

And a page like

```
<html>
<body>
  #{personBean.person.addresses[0].street}<br/>
  #{personBean.person.addresses[0].number}<br/>
  #{personBean.person.addresses[0].city}<br/>

  #{personBean.person.company.address.street}<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

In this situation I can do the `em.find()` in a synchronized way to keep using the `EntityManager` in a thread safe manner. But what about the page itself? I assume JSF will load the values in parallel?

Any suggestions? Or is there no problem?

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: Thread-safety is not a problem because you get a dedicated EntityManger per Transaction. The problem is lazy loading. The EntityManger perstence context will be closed when you JSF access the addresses collection. Which AppServer are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java-SE with Tomcat. So fully manual transaction management. So what I do is that I create an EntityManager for the bean that lives during the Session. The Person stays 'managed' and lazy loading will have the entityManager